# Performance issues with groupwise MAX in JOIN clause

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-5.7

## Problem

I have some assets in my application which are updated from time to time in an asynchronous fashion.

The example I'm gonna use here is `Vehicles`. There are two tables:

- **`Vehicles`:** holds information about the vehicles themselves
- **`VehicleUpdates`:** holds information about all updates that happened for that vehicle.

The relevant parts of the table structure are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Vehicles` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `organizationId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `plate` char(7) NOT NULL,
  `vehicleInfo` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_Vehicles_orgId_plate_idx` (`organizationId`,`plate`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Vehicles_createdAt_idx` (`createdAt`),
);

CREATE TABLE `VehicleUpdates` (
  `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `organizationId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `vehiclePlate` char(7) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx` (`organizationId`,`vehiclePlate`,`createdAt`) USING BTREE
);
```

Now I have a new requirement in which **I must return the latest update information along side the vehicle information itself**.

## Groupwise MAX Solutions

After digging a little, I've found [this blog article](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max). I then tried to use the suggested "uncorrelated subquery" approach, since it's deemed the best one:

### Uncorrelated subquery

```sql
SELECT  vu1.*
    FROM VehicleUpdates AS vu1
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  vehiclePlate, organizationId, MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt
            FROM  VehicleUpdates
            GROUP BY organizationId, vehiclePlate
      ) AS vu2 USING (organizationId, vehiclePlate, createdAt);
```

This query has an average execution time of `275 ms` in my production database.

I thought that was too slow, so I decided to give the "LEFT JOIN" approach a shot:

### The Duds: LEFT JOIN

```sql
SELECT  vu1.*
    FROM  VehicleUpdates AS vu1
    LEFT JOIN  VehicleUpdates AS vu2 ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId and vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
      AND  vu2.createdAt > vu1.createdAt
    WHERE  vu2.id IS NULL;
```

This one performed way better, with an average execution time of `40 ms`. Good enough for me.

Then I needed to run this query as part of the query on the `Vehicles` table.

## Current results

The following query would satisfy my requirements:

```sql
SELECT  v.*, vu1.*
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN VehicleUpdates AS vu1 
    ON v.plate = vu1.vehiclePlate 
        AND v.organizationId = vu1.organizationId
LEFT JOIN  VehicleUpdates AS vu2 
    ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId 
        AND vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
        AND  vu2.createdAt > vu1.createdAt
WHERE  vu2.id IS NULL;
```

The problem is that it takes `20 s` (!) to run. Huge problem!

But I never do a full table scan on production. The query is always limited to a single `organizationId` and it's paged, so I return at most 100 lines per page, so I ran the following query:

```sql
SELECT  v.*, vu1.*
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN VehicleUpdates AS vu1 
    ON v.plate = vu1.vehiclePlate 
        AND v.organizationId = vu1.organizationId
LEFT JOIN  VehicleUpdates AS vu2 
    ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId 
        AND vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
        AND  vu2.createdAt > vu1.createdAt
WHERE vu2.id IS NULL
    and v.organizationId = '<some organization ID>'
LIMIT 100;
```

Now it takes from `750 ms` to `11 s` to run, depending on how many vehicles are associated with. Not good enough.

Running `explain` for the query above got me:

```sql
"select_type" | "table" | "type" | "possible_keys"                                        | "key"                                      | "key_len" | "ref"                               | "rows" | "filtered" | "Extra"
SIMPLE        | v       | ref    | unq_Vehicles_orgId_plate_idx,Vehicles_orgId_status_idx | unq_Vehicles_orgId_plate_idx               | "202"     | const                               | 30     | 100        |
SIMPLE        | vu1     | ALL    |                                                        |                                            |           |                                     | 263171 | 100        | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
SIMPLE        | vu2     | ref    | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx             | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "173"     | vu1.organizationId,vu1.vehiclePlate | 10     | 10         | Using where; Not exists; Using index
```

What strikes me is that the `vu1` table is running a full table scan, even though the left-most table `Vehicles` is being filtered using an indexed column `organizationId`, which is also indexed in `VehicleUpdates`.

So I decided to give the "uncorrelated subquery" another try and ran:

```sql
SELECT  v.*, vu.*
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  vu1.*
        FROM VehicleUpdates AS vu1
        JOIN
          ( SELECT  vehiclePlate, organizationId, MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt
                FROM  VehicleUpdates
                GROUP BY organizationId, vehiclePlate
          ) AS vu2 USING (organizationId, vehiclePlate, createdAt)
) AS vu 
    ON vu.organizationId = v.organizationId 
        AND vu.vehiclePlate = v.plate
WHERE v.organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>'
LIMIT 100;
```

This time the execution time varies from `1.4 s` to `13 s`, depending on how many entries there was in the `Vehicles` table for a given `organizationId`. Unacceptable for my application.

Running `explain` got me:

```sql
| "select_type" | "table"        | "type" | "possible_keys"                            | "key"                                      | "key_len" | "ref"                                             | "rows" | "filtered" | "Extra"
| PRIMARY       | v              | ALL    |                                            |                                            |           |                                                   | 14456  | 100        |
| PRIMARY       | <derived3>     | ALL    |                                            |                                            |           |                                                   | 29289  | 100        | Using where
| PRIMARY       | vu1            | ref    | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "327"     | vu2.organizationId,vu2.vehiclePlate,vu2.createdAt | 1      | 100        | Using where
| DERIVED       | VehicleUpdates | range  | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "323"     |                                                   | 29289  | 100        | Using index for group-by
```

---

## Current Results - UPDATED

I noticed that adding the specific `organizationId` clause can increase the performance.

### LEFT JOIN

Running:

```sql
SELECT  v.*, vu1.*
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN VehicleUpdates AS vu1 
    ON v.plate = vu1.vehiclePlate 
        AND v.organizationId = vu1.organizationId
        AND vu1.organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>' -- <--------
LEFT JOIN  VehicleUpdates AS vu2 
    ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId 
        AND vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
        AND vu2.createdAt > vu1.createdAt
WHERE vu2.id IS NULL
    and v.organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>' -- <-----------
LIMIT 100;
```

I get execution times varying from `65 ms` (acceptable) to `2.5 s` (not acceptable).

### Uncorrelated query

Putting a `organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>'` clause in the "main" query and the join **external** subquery:

```sql
SELECT  v.*, vu.*
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  vu1.*
        FROM VehicleUpdates AS vu1
        JOIN
          ( SELECT  vehiclePlate, organizationId, MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt
                FROM  VehicleUpdates
                GROUP BY organizationId, vehiclePlate
          ) AS vu2 ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId
                and vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
                and vu1.createdAt = vu2.createdAt
        WHERE organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>' -- <--------
    ) AS vu 
        ON vu.organizationId = v.organizationId 
            AND vu.vehiclePlate = v.plate
where
    v.organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>' -- <---------
LIMIT 100;
```

I get execution times varying from `450 ms` (not acceptable) to `900 ms` (not acceptable).

Putting a `organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>'` clause in the "main" query and the join **internal** subquery:

```sql
SELECT  v.*, vu.*
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  vu1.*
        FROM VehicleUpdates AS vu1
        JOIN
          ( SELECT  vehiclePlate, organizationId, MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt
                FROM  VehicleUpdates
                WHERE organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>' -- <--------
                GROUP BY organizationId, vehiclePlate
          ) AS vu2 ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId
                and vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
                and vu1.createdAt = vu2.createdAt
    ) AS vu 
        ON vu.organizationId = v.organizationId 
            AND vu.vehiclePlate = v.plate
where
    v.organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>' -- <---------
LIMIT 100;
```

I get execution times varying from `225 ms` (acceptable) to `500 ms` (not acceptable).

---

Are there any better ways of handling such query?

## Database Information

- MySQL
- Version: 5.7.23-log (Amazon RDS)
- Engine: InnoDB

Comment: `organizationId` is  `VARCHAR(50)` in one table and `VARCHAR(100)` in the other. Fix that for start and run your tests again.

Comment: Good eye! I missed that. I'll update the question with the results from the updated schema.

Comment: Thanks for putting my blog to the test.  I have suspected that changes to the Optimizer have messed with my conclusions.  Did you run each timing test twice, and take the second result?  (The first gets I/O done; the second sees things cached.)

Comment: The final two queries are at risk from a different direction:  a derived table in a `LEFT JOIN`.  It may have to re-evaluate that many times.  Can you change to `JOIN` without ruining the output?

Comment: Did you grab the Handler STATUS values?  A brief note on it is [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) .

Comment: @RickJames the man himself :D. What an honor! I know exactly which organizations have the less and the most vehicles, so I've ran the query for each one of them a few times.

About the change on the JOIN type, I'm affraid I can't do that because some vehicles might not have been updated yet, so there'll be no rows related to them in the `VehicleUpdate` table, but I still need to return them.

Comment: About the Handler STATUS, I didn't know about it (I'm not a DBA). However, this table is not updated all the time. Updates comes from a batch that runs every day at 5 a.m. (UTC), so by the time I was writing those queries, the dataset was pretty much stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel so stupid! Just found the problem.

For some reason, `Vehicles` and `VehicleUpdates` had **different charsets** (`utf8mb4` and `utf8`, respectively) in production.

That's the reason why the `EXPLAIN` result for the "uncorrelated subquery" approach had a full table scan in one of its steps:

```
| "select_type" | "table"        | "type" | "possible_keys"                            | "key"                                      | "key_len" | "ref"                                             | "rows" | "filtered" | "Extra"
| PRIMARY       | v              | ALL    |                                            |                                            |           |                                                   | 14456  | 100        |
| PRIMARY       | <derived3>     | ALL    |                                            |                                            |           |                                                   | 29289  | 100        | Using where
| PRIMARY       | vu1            | ref    | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "327"     | vu2.organizationId,vu2.vehiclePlate,vu2.createdAt | 1      | 100        | Using where
| DERIVED       | VehicleUpdates | range  | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "323"     |                                                   | 29289  | 100        | Using index for group-by
```

After converting `VehicleUpdates` to `utf8mb4`, the `EXPLAIN` result is:

```
| "select_type" | "table"        | "type" | "possible_keys"                            | "key"                                      | "key_len" | "ref"                                           | "rows" | "filtered" | "Extra"
| PRIMARY       | v              | ref    | Vehicles_orgId_status_idx                  | Vehicles_orgId_status_idx                  | "202"     | const                                           | 188    | 100        |
| PRIMARY       | <derived2>     | ref    | <auto_key1>                                | <auto_key1>                                | "230"     | v.plate,v.organizationId                        | 10     | 100        |
| PRIMARY       | vu1            | ref    | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "234"     | v.organizationId,vu2.vehiclePlate,vu2.createdAt | 1      | 100        | Using where
| DERIVED       | VehicleUpdates | ref    | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "202"     | const                                           | 24090  | 100        | Using where; Using index
```

Likewise, the "LEFT JOIN" approach execution plan changed from:

```
| "select_type" | "table" | "type" | "possible_keys"                                        | "key"                                      | "key_len" | "ref"                               | "rows" | "filtered" | "Extra"
| SIMPLE        | v       | ref    | unq_Vehicles_orgId_plate_idx,Vehicles_orgId_status_idx | unq_Vehicles_orgId_plate_idx               | "202"     | const                               | 30     | 100        |
| SIMPLE        | vu1     | ALL    |                                                        |                                            |           |                                     | 263171 | 100        | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
| SIMPLE        | vu2     | ref    | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx             | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "173"     | vu1.organizationId,vu1.vehiclePlate | 10     | 10         | Using where; Not exists; Using index
```

To:

```
| "select_type" | "table" | "type" | "possible_keys"                            | "key"                                      | "key_len" | "ref"                               | "rows" | "filtered" | "Extra"
| SIMPLE        | v       | ref    | Vehicles_orgId_status_idx                  | Vehicles_orgId_status_idx                  | "202"     | const                               | 188    | 100        |
| SIMPLE        | vu1     | ref    | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "230"     | v.organizationId,v.plate            | 9      | 100        |
| SIMPLE        | vu2     | ref    | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | VehicleUpdates_orgId_vhclPlt_createdAt_idx | "230"     | vu1.organizationId,vu1.vehiclePlate | 9      | 10         | Using where; Not exists; Using index
```

So, the performance now for the different queries are:

### LEFT JOIN

```sql
SELECT v.*, vu1.*
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN VehicleUpdates AS vu1 
    ON v.plate = vu1.vehiclePlate 
        AND v.organizationId = vu1.organizationId
LEFT JOIN  VehicleUpdates AS vu2 
    ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId 
        AND vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
        AND vu2.createdAt > vu1.createdAt
where v.organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>'
    AND vu2.id IS NULL
LIMIT 100;
```

Always runs bellow `50 ms`.

### Uncorrelated subquery without WHERE in the inner query:

```sql
SELECT v.*, vu1.* 
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN (
        VehicleUpdates AS vu1
        JOIN
          ( SELECT  vehiclePlate, organizationId, MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt
                FROM  VehicleUpdates
                GROUP BY organizationId, vehiclePlate
          ) AS vu2 ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId
                and vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
                and vu1.createdAt = vu2.createdAt
    )
        ON vu1.organizationId = v.organizationId 
            AND vu1.vehiclePlate = v.plate
where
    v.organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>'
LIMIT 100;
```

Runs on average in `300 ms`.

### Uncorrelated subquery with WHERE in the inner query:

```sql
SELECT v.*, vu1.* 
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN (
        VehicleUpdates AS vu1
        JOIN
          ( SELECT  vehiclePlate, organizationId, MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt
                FROM  VehicleUpdates
                WHERE organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>' -- <-- HERE
                GROUP BY organizationId, vehiclePlate
          ) AS vu2 ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId
                and vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
                and vu1.createdAt = vu2.createdAt
    )
        ON vu1.organizationId = v.organizationId 
            AND vu1.vehiclePlate = v.plate
where
    v.organizationId = '<SOME ORGANIZATION ID>'
LIMIT 100;
```

Also always runs bellow `50 ms`.

---

I decided to stick with the "LEFT JOIN" approach because it allows me to create a view to represent the inner query, so I can simplify the query for returning the vehicles.

I cannot do this with the "uncorrelated subquery", because it requires the `WHERE organizationId = '<ORGANIZATION ID>'` clause in the inner query, so the view would not be as efficient.

Comment: @RickJames looks like theses results go against what could be observed before 5.7: LEFT JOIN  has a better performance than the Uncorrelated Subquery.

Comment: Hmmm -- Thanks for discovering that and pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on the right track with putting the `organizationId` into strategic parts of your query.

Try this slightly modified version of your "uncorrelated subquery" query:

```
SELECT  v.*, vu1.*
FROM  Vehicles AS v
LEFT JOIN (
        VehicleUpdates AS vu1
        JOIN
          ( SELECT  vehiclePlate, organizationId, MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt
                FROM  VehicleUpdates
                WHERE organizationId = 'A100'
                GROUP BY organizationId, vehiclePlate
          ) AS vu2 ON vu1.organizationId = vu2.organizationId
                and vu1.vehiclePlate = vu2.vehiclePlate
                and vu1.createdAt = vu2.createdAt
    )
        ON vu1.organizationId = v.organizationId 
            AND vu1.vehiclePlate = v.plate
where
    v.organizationId = 'A100'
LIMIT 100;
```

This version of the query avoids the intermediate `SELECT *` on the LEFT JOINed table, and so not have to lose speed with an intermediate result.

The only difference between my query and yours is I dropped the `SELECT vu1.* FROM` and `AS vu` from the query, and the updated all the occurrences of `vu` to `vu1`.

It is useful little trick that help out in situations where you need to use an INNER JOIN on a table that needs to be LEFT JOINed to the main query, which is exactly your case.

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. It seems like it sped up the queries with less results (from ~ 190 ms to ~ 150ms), but had no effect on the ones with more results (still 500ms).

Comment: Yeah, I was shocked when I first realized that this was possible a couple years back. Handy thing though. As for the speed, is it possible to make `(organizationId,vehiclePlate, createdAt)` the primary key of `VehicleUpdates`? If so, it should reduce the speed loss caused by the secondary lookup that is occurring for all of your query attempts as a result of the `SELECT vu.*`. Alternatively, you can try adding all the remaining columns to your index in that table. Making it your PK is better, but adding the columns may work as well.